# Is there a way to refresh/update the server certificate pair in C++ gRPC server without restarting? (Prefer not to use the experimental namespace)

Tags: server, certificate, grpc

Need to refresh the server certificate pair when they expire without restarting to avoid disruption.
We have critical clients that send data to our gRPC server. We are trying to find a way to auto update/refresh the server certificates pair when they expire without disconnecting the clients. We would like the current connecting clients to continue working while new clients will require to use the new certificates. Google a lot but haven't found any discussion that works. Found some articles discussing about the experimental APIs but prefer not to use them. We are implementing our gRPC server in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The [`TlsServerCredentials` API](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/f11c010e5183125c0cd09e4c12f31222d9bb0fb2/include/grpcpp/security/server_credentials.h#L129) is experimental, but it supports what you are looking for. We plan on de-experimentalizing it, but can't commit to any timelines.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to reload the server credentials when using the `SslServerCredentials` API.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on msteve's answer on how I use the `TlsServerCredentials` API.

Using the `ServerBuilder`:

```
grpc::ServerBuilder builder;
```

First create a shared pointer to the `FileWatcherCertificateProvider` (which
inherits from the `CertificateProviderInterface`). Give it the path to your private key and identity certificate and how often the library should check the files for updates. Note that there are a couple of constructors here, dependent on how you want to use it.

```
auto provider = std::make_shared<grpc::experimental::FileWatcherCertificateProvider> (
         private_key_path, identity_certificate_path, refresh_interval_sec);
```

Then create an instance of `TlsServerCredentialsOptions`, providing a pointer to a `CertificateProviderInterface` object. Lastly, call `watch_identity_key_cert_pairs()` to activate the watch.

```
grpc::experimental::TlsServerCredentialsOptions tls_options(provider);
tls_options.watch_identity_key_cert_pairs();
```

Using the options, create an instance of `TlsServerCredentials` and provide it as a `std::shared_ptr\<ServerCredentials\>` to `AddListeningPort` on the builder.

```
auto creds = grpc::experimental::TlsServerCredentials(tls_options);
builder.AddListeningPort(addr_uri, creds);
```